# eCommerce session data persistence

Tags: php, session, e-commerce

I'm currently building a shopping cart for an eCommerce site and am wondering about the best way to persist user data in the session during the checkout process.

The user flow works is as follows:

shopping cart -> login/register -> select delivery address -> confirm -> pay

My issue is once a user is logged in, I want to display a list of their delivery addresses so they can select one. The easiest way to do this is querying the model by the user's id, but my concern is for security - my first thought was to store the user id in the session and then use this to retrieve the addresses. However there's nothing to stop another user potentially hijacking this id (just by guessing random numbers) and revealing addresses for other users. I could perhaps use their email address, but this too could potentially be guessed. Is my best bet to use a combination of the two, or is there a better way?

Comment: If your session IDs are so weak as to be easily guessable, then your store should not exist in the first place. PHP's default sessions IDs are random 32-char alpha-numeric strings, and are NOT trivially guessable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has built-in session capability. It loads a unique cookie to the browser and allows you to keep all session data on the server-side via the `$_SESSION` array. The cookie ID is unique for the session, not the user, so it changes each time the user signs in (if the cookie has expired). If you conduct the session in https, it's very secure. Without https, the session *is* vulnerable to someone with the (special) knowledge and inclination to intercept the cookie data, though such an interception is not easy. Depending on *how* secure you want to be, running without https may or may not be acceptable for you.

You can read more about PHP session capability here:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: Thank you both. I've misunderstood how $_SESSION cookies work, I was under the (I now realise stupid) impression that data was stored in the cookie, not just the session id. I had confused myself further by finding session data when searching my machine but I now realise this was the corresponding server side data stored in my xampp localhost!

Comment: To be clear, if you create your *own* cookies, you *can* store session data *in* the cookie. But that's not how PHP Sessions do it. They store everything server-side and just put a unique ID in the cookie. The client supplies the cookie data (the session ID) in the request, and then the server is able to access the correct session data in the `$_SESSION` array.